# Grouping continuous data with a skewed shape

Tags: clustering

I am currently working with a dataset of Facebook posts that have variables such as total engagement and views. I am trying to group these two variables into discrete levels according to how big the value is (for example, divide views in 10 clusters, 0 for lowest and 10 for highest). These discrete groups are then used to compare the data across different datasets.

I am trying to find the best approach to do this, and at the moment I have tried:

1. Quantile based discretization (qcut in Python), but it does not work exactly as expected as given the large number of 0s it create a large cluster and then some small ones
2. Kmeans clustering, which works decently but tends to produce groups that are a bit small even with a low number of clusters

I wanted to check if anyone has any suggestions on the best way to divide a continuous variable with a very large range into groups

Comment: The best approach likely is not to group at all, but to employ the levels directly in your comparison.

Comment: I agree with @whuber.  There are cases where you do want to make groups. Not many, but some. But most of these are based on a prior, substantive reasons.  If you have a good reason for grouping, let us know.